# Not geting right solution with solve_ivp

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I am trying to solve the differential equation using **solve_ivp**, but I am not getting the right solution. However, I obtained the right solution using **ideint**. Do I have some problems with the solve_ipv program?

ODEINT program :

```
# Arhenius Function
def Arhenius(a, T):
    dadT = np.exp(lnA)/v * np.exp(- E / (8.3144 * T)) * c * np.abs(a) ** m * np.abs((1 - np.abs(a))) ** n
    return dadT

# Initial data
pt = 100000
T0 = 273
Tf = 1500
a0 = 0.0000000001
T = np.linspace(T0, Tf, pt)

a_sol = np.zeros(pt)
dadt = np.zeros(pt)

# ODE solve
a_t = odeint(Arhenius, a0, T)

# For removing errored values and have maximum at 1 
search1 = np.where(np.isclose(a_t, 1))
try:
    ia_1 = search1[0][0]
    a_sol[0,:] = a_t[:,0]
    a_sol[0,ia_1+1:pt] = 1
except:
    a_sol = a_t[:,0]

#  Calculate the new derivative
dadt = np.exp(lnA) * np.exp(- E / (8.3144 * T)) * c * np.abs(a_sol) ** m * np.abs((1 - a_sol)) ** n
```

PROGRAM with solve_ivp :

```
# Arhenius Function
def Arhenius(a, T):
    dadT = np.exp(lnA) * np.exp(- E / (8.3144 * T)) * c * np.abs(a) ** m * np.abs((1 - np.abs(a))) ** n
    return dadT

# Initial data
pt = 100000
T0 = 273
Tf = 1500
a0 = 0.0000000001
T = np.linspace(T0, Tf, pt)

a_sol = np.zeros(pt)
dadt = np.zeros(pt)

# ODE solve
a_t = solve_ivp(Arhenius, t_span = (T0, Tf), y0 = (a0,), t_eval = T, method = 'RK45')
a_sol= a_t.y

#  Calculate the new derivative    
dadt = np.exp(lnA) * np.exp(- E / (8.3144 * T)) * c * np.abs(a_sol) ** m * np.abs((1 - a_sol)) ** n
```

Comment: Values of constants can be : lnA = 36, E = 125000, c= 1, m = 0, n= 1.5, v = 5